# No error but the desired screen does not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It should be implemented on the screen, but no error, but the implementation is not good. I will attach only the necessary parts.

I can't find similar data. I don't know why.
Please take a look at the code

Trades.js

```
const showFilledOrders = (filledOrders) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {
        filledOrders.map((order) => {
          return (<tr >
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td>Baz</td>
          </tr>)
        })
      }
    </tbody>
  )
}


class Trades extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
        <div className="card-header">
          Trades
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <table className="table table-dark table-sm small">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>DAPP</th>
                <th>DAPP/ETH</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            not working -> {
              this.props.filledOrdersLoaded
                ? showFilledOrders(this.props.filledOrders)
                : <tbody></tbody>
            }
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

selectors.js

```
const filledOrdersLoaded = state => get(state, 'exchange.filledOrders.loaded', false)
export const filledOrdersLoadedSelector = createSelector(filledOrdersLoaded, loaded => loaded)

const filledOrders = state => get(state, 'exchange.filledOrders.data', [])
export const filledOrdersSelector = createSelector(filledOrders, (orders) => {
  // Sort orders by date ascending for price comparison
  orders = orders.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp)
  // Decorate the orders
  orders = decorateFilledOrders(orders)
  // Sort orders by date descending for display
  orders = orders.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
  return orders
})
```

Comment: using react devtools, can you inspect and confirm the props passed to your component are what you expect? (e.g. `filledOrdersLoaded` is `true` and `filledOrders` is a non-empty array)

Comment: thank you for reply  i will install redux dev tools and try it again